# Python use title or keyword to print paragraph from text file

Tags: python, text

I have an text file, and I want to search 'some keyword',and print that whole paragraph.

The text file is from p d f, so it is like:

8. REFERENCES

[1] The Google Search Engine: Commercial search engine
founded by the originators of P.
a a a:// s s s s s s s/.
[2] The Open Directory Pro j: Web directory for over
2.5 million URLs.
h t t p://z.org/.
[3] ‘More Evil Than Dr. Evil?’
h t t p://s e a r com/sere p o r t/99/11-
google.html.
[4] Krishna Bharat and Mon i k a R. Improved
algorithms for topic distillation in a hyperlinked

Now I can only print one line

```
f = open('Desktop\\2002\\1. t x t','r')
lines = f. read lines()
for lines in lines:
   if "[1]" in lines:
       print(lines)
```

ans:The Google Search Engine: Commercial search engine

I want a keyword like 'REFERENCES', and print:
[1] The Google Search Engine: Commercial search engine founded by the originators of P.

[2] The Open Directory Pro j e ct: Web directory for over 2.5 million URLs.
.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

After your search has found the keyword you could assume how the next parts will look.

So you could skip the next line and after that print each line until another empty line is coming up.

```
f = open('Desktop\\2002\\1. t x t','r')
lines = f. read lines()
currentParagraph = False
for line in lines:
   if "[1]" in line and not currentParagraph:
       print(line)
       currentParagraph = True
       continue
   if currentParagraph:
       print(line)
       if line == "":
           break
```

You have to check however wheter there are line break symbols in the "empty" lines ("\n").

Comment: It's work.I change code like this ' if line == "AAA": break ', but I don't need AAA this word, how can i do?

Comment: the `if line == ""` is for the check if the paragraph has ended. If your paragraphs dont end on AAA then you shouldn't change it to AAA. The check for a heading is in  `if "[1]" in line ....`